# Navbar not exiting the container

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to make a hero container that have a navbar that will looks like part of the hero container, i want the navbar to be sticky so when i scroll it will be on top the whole time but when i scroll down the navbar will not even past the hero container.
Here's the html

```
<section class="heroContainer">
  <nav></nav>
</section>
```

here's the css

```
.heroContainer{
   position:relative;
}
nav{
   position:sticky;
   top:0;
   left:0;;
}
```

Comment: Please add enough code to create a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the slight modification to your CSS and the sticky functionality might not work if the content in the Hero section is long enough

```
.heroContainer {
    position: relative;
}

.navbar {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #555;
    padding: 10px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for answering but i came up width the different solution. I used position fixed rather than sticky because when i use sticky it wont overflow to the parent element while fixed i just needed to add z-index greater than the size of parent content

Answer (score -1):

There is an issue in your navbar's style code.
Here is your nav' CSS:

```css
nav{
     position:sticky;
     top:0;
     background:grey;
     padding:10px;``
     z-index:99
}
```